# Why the need for both const reference and const member function?

Tags: c++, member-functions, const-reference

I'm doing the exercises from "Programming Principles and Practice using C++" 
and I found a class with this member function [here](https://github.com/ltr01/stroustrup-ppp-1/blob/master/chapter09/chapter09_ex02.cpp):

```
const vector<string> &get_name() const { return name; }
```

where name is a vector:  `vector< string> name`;

The book presents 2 concepts so far (up to page 235):

1. return a const reference to prevent the function to change the returning value:

   ```
   const vector<string> &get_name() { return name; }
   ```
2. a const member function that cannot modify the object. in this case, it would be like this:

   ```
   vector<string> get_name() const { return name; }
   ```

Maybe I'm not getting this completely, but aren't those 2 concepts the same? 
Not wanting to change the "name" vector.

Why the need for both "const"?

Thanks to anyone taking the time to reply!

Comment: They aren't the same because the second version has to make a (potentially expensive) copy of `name`.

Comment: First `const` apply to returned object only, and the method cannot be called on const instance/object. the second one apply to instance/object, so both const/non-const instance can call that method.

Comment: The first says "you're not allowed  to change this thing that you're asking for, and I might change while you ask", the second says "I'm not going to change if you ask for this thing, and you can do whatever you want with the thing I give you". Those are not the same concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. return a const reference to prevent the function to change the returning value
> 2. a const member function that cannot modify the object. in this case, it would be like this

This could have been a bit more clearer, I'll try my shot at explaining it better.

Returning a const reference prevent the *returned object* to be mutated by *callers*.

Here's an example:

```
// let get_name be `const std::vector<std::string>& get_name()`

np1.get_name().size(); // ok, size is a const function of vector
np1.get_name().push_back("hello"); // ERROR! push_back is not a const function of vector
```

So indeed, a caller cannot change the `name` vector. The return type is const qualified.

However, if the function `get_name` itself is not const qualified (not the return type), then it is allowed to change name from the class itself.

You see, member functions receive a hidden `this` parameter, which is a pointer to the object being called on. The pointer can either point to a const object, or a mutable object. Here's the comparison:

```
// returning const ref, callers cannot change the name vector
const std::vector<std::string>& get_name() {
    // The function receive a `this` that points to a mutable,
    // we can change the name from the inside
    this->name.push_back("another");
    return name;
}

// the `this` pointer points to const -----v---v
const std::vector<std::string>& get_name() const {
    this->name.push_back("another"); // ERROR! Cannot mutate member of const object
    return name;
}
```

Const-qualified member function are really useful for the caller, as it knows that whenever this function is called, its state won't change.

For example, not only you know that the `vector::size()` function won't mutate the vector, but the compiler guarantees it since it's a const qualified member function.

And for the last bit, the code you posted here:

```
vector<string> get_name() const { return name; }
```

This will not return a reference, but will make a copy. The caller can mutate the copy however it wants, but cannot mutate `name` itself.

Here's an example of a copy mutated:

```
auto name_copy = np1.get_name();

name_copy.push_back("another name"); // works, we mutated the copy by adding an element
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Guillaume! it really helps.
If I may ask another question, how do you change the copy for the last line: 
 vector<string> get_name() const { return name; }

Comment: could you please take a look at my code here?
https://github.com/ltr01/PPPCpp-Tests/blob/master/9.3_test2.cpp

I defined the functions get_name1(), get_name2() and get_name3() like in your examples.
And the functions 1 and 2 behave just like you said.
But after creating the object np3 and adding another element to it, I still cannot see that new element. 
I'm doing something wrong or I still don't get something ? Thanks a lot for taking the time for this! It really helps.

Comment: @Theodore You won't be able to mutate `name` using `get_name3()`. Since you return a copy, any mutation you do such as `push_back` will be done on the copy, not the original `name` object. If you want mutable access, use `std::vector<std::string>& get_name()`. Since the returned reference is non const, you will be able to mutate the referenced object.

Comment: I finally succeeded to push_back on a copy, inside the function get_name3(). That's what I couldn't do. And I get what you mean by mutating the referenced object. WOW I understand so much more since 24h ago! Thanks a lot, Guillaume!

Answer (score 1):

A member-function has an implicit `this`-reference.

And the referenced object can be `const`-qualified, allowing the member-function to be called on a constant object, by following the parameter-list in the declaration with `const`.

Whether that member-function also returns a reference to some constant data may be strongly correlated, but is still completely the programmers decision.

Answer (score 1):

This case return a const reference to `vector<string>`, and we cannot change this vector. But we can change `vector<string> name` in this function.

```
const vector<string> &get_name() { return name; }
```

In this case return a copy of `vector<string>`, and we can change this vector, because it's already another vector. In this function we cannot change `vector<string> name`.

```
vector<string> get_name() const { return name; }
```